# R changing data type in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I am having trouble with data frames in R. I create the data frame with defined datatypes but when I append data it changes the data type. I don't understand why this is happening or the find a solution.  Can anyone help?

```
df<- data.frame(year=integer(), yes_no=character())
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(2022 ,"Y")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

*Vectors are sometimes also referred to as the ‘nuts & bolts’ in R as they build the basis for all complex objects such as data frames or fitted regression models:*

- You "pass" an atomic vector `c(2022, "Y")` to row 1 of `df`. In R atomic vectors contain **only elements of same type** e.g. all numeric, or all character...etc...
- Atomic vectors are different to lists, lists can contain different types.
- Atomic vectors are constructed with the `c()` function or the `vector` function.

**In your case:** character is over integer in the hierarchy of atomic vectors: therefore `2022` is transformed to character type.

**Solution:**

```
df$year <- as.integer(df$year)
str(df)
```

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ year  : int 2022
 $ yes_no: chr "Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to do something like :

```
df<- data.frame(year=numeric(), yes_no=character())
df <- rbind(df, list(2022 ,"Y"))
```

Comment: Thanks..........

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the code is correct and doing what is expected from a `data.frame` type. I suggest to use a conversion like @TarJae mentioned or switch to tibbles as I describe below:

```
> df <- data.frame(year=integer(), yes_no=character())
> 
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(df$year)
[1] "integer"
> class(df$yes_no)
[1] "factor"
> 
> df <- tibble(year=integer(), yes_no=character())
> 
> class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(df$year)
[1] "integer"
> class(df$yes_no)
[1] "character"
>
```

I hope this is helpful !!

Kind regards,
Augusto.

Comment: Thankyou.........

Comment: My pleasure !

Let me know if you need anything else !!

Comment: Using a tibble versus a base data frame doesn't change the fact that a column / vector will only have a single type